# Should we allow offensive source code?

Tags: discussion, offensive

I lately stumbled upon a member who adds racist code snippets in his posts.

An example taken from one of his questions:

```
NSString *attributedString = @"Did hitler do nothing wrong?";

[yesBtn setTitle:@"Yes!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yesBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(userIsAwesome:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[noBtn setTitle:@"No!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[noBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(userIsAFuckwit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

OK, I am a ****wit.

On other occasion, he added "Jew" to an example about swear words.

I am from Germany, I grew up with the knowledge that it was my people that killed at least 6 million people in the concentration Camps and started a war that in the end killed at least 50 million people all over the world.

One good thing to say about Germany: It doesn't shut its eyes about its responsibilities and guilt of this genocide. So here this user's code could be treated as incitement of the masses and he could go to jail. But I know that in other countries it might be considered okay as per freedom of speech.

So, how about Stack Overflow: Do we want to allow hate speech in sample code or should we delete it? How to deal with members using it?

Comment: The [question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23436476) as mentioned in this ques.. uhrm.

Comment: Coming up: Should we allow *"F*ckwit"* in questions?

Comment: It is gone, problem solved.  So, no.

Comment: It is a poor attempt at humour. I note that the user has also gotten into trouble for different reasons, so their judgement does appear impaired.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that you can't initialize an `NSAttributedString` with a literal `NSString`. My eyes!

Comment: oh sorry, my fault. I shortened the code.

Comment: @Bart: to be clear: I don't want to talk about strong languages in general. I don't mind it to much. I talk about hate speech, speech directed against individuals or groups of people.

Comment: Oh, the user is gone. Was he banned or did he revoke his profile?

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Oops, I accidentally the account.

Comment: ios developers, sheesh.  Their rotten language apparently also rots their tiny hearts.

Comment: 75K reputation but still a troll… so sad.

Comment: @Will - http://i.stack.imgur.com/MN6lR.jpg

Comment: @BradLarson [no](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XPZPl.jpg)

Comment: StackOverflow devolution: from Godwin's law to LOLCats, in a space of one comment thread :)

Comment: On a technical nitpick, "Freedom of Speech" refers to a narrow area of **Government actions** restricting speech. StackExchange isn't a government agent (yet, or that we known of) and therefore the concept is technically speaking inapplicable. Meaning, they can choose to impose pretty much ANY restrictions they want.

Comment: @DVK [XKCD: "Free Speech"](http://xkcd.com/1357/).

Comment: just a reminder: not all of us fall under U.S. jurisdiction.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the phrase in question is [an internet meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/dub-the-dew) (likely nsfw content).  It might not be meant to *only* offend.

Comment: @DVK That's not how people who invoke [freedom of speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech) in argument usually mean it. They're usually claiming a moral right to express themselves without being censored or punished for their speech - whether by the government, a large organisation like SO, or an angry mob. There is legitimate argument to be had about how to balance freedom of speech against other moral concerns, certainly. But folks like you refusing to acknowledge that anyone could see 'freedom of speech' as anything but a (purely American) legal issue is a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @Cupcake I despise that particular XKCD comic and it goes against dearly held political beliefs of mine. The wonderful Slate Star Codex summarises my feelings well: *... the new xkcd-approved leftist orthodoxy that free speech means absolutely nothing except that the government can’t arrest you borrows from the worst parts of libertarianism and is about as anti-leftist as you can get. Libertarians are the ones who say that “rights” mean only that the government can’t take something away from you.* I also commend this view: http://fredrikdeboer.com/2014/04/18/free-speech-rights-and-ability/

Comment: @Mark I understand your point of view, but as an American, I can say with confidence that when *Americans* invoke "freedom of speech" in an argument, they do in fact mean to invoke the *right* that they are guaranteed by the federal government's constitution. And in that case, DVK's comment (and the XKCD cartoon) are perfectly apt. They may *also* imply a whole other set of moral rights, but the legal right is inevitably the primary justification. If you ask them why freedom of speech is important to protect, they won't give you a good argument, they'll say because the Constitution says so.

Comment: Congratulations, you found a /b/tard. While this is certainly inappropriate for SO, I believe this example is a reference to the [trolling of a mountain dew marketing campaign](http://www.manolith.com/2012/08/15/4chan-shuts-down-mountain-dew-naming-contest-after-hitler-did-nothing-wrong-gets-most-votes/); so I'd say the user is probably not a neo-nazi but just trying really hard to be edgy...

Comment: Disgusting as this is, why is it on the Community Bulletin?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm probably because the Community Bulletin is filled by an algorithm and not by humans. Specifically, because this question attracted a fair number of views, votes, comments and answers.

Comment: FYI free speech in the US - in the US it is usually against the law to try to restrict someone from expressing their opinions, no matter how offensive (this includes "hate speech"). However this does not imply that anyone is obligated to provide them a platform for such speech - in particular SO can delete any post they want for any reason and doing so does not violate the posters 1st amendment rights.

Comment: @Huperniketes "But I know that in other countries it might be considered okay as per freedom of speech." I think we are in agreement that per OPs question, there is nothing that makes it necessary to tolerate speech like this on SO - although it's not a crime as it might be in Germany. Just trying to clarify for OP.

Comment: Couldn't be simpler - just delete it.  (regarding "free speech in the USA" is that a joke?  from 1950 or something?  Good grief.  USA is the land of hyper- political correctness, guantanamo bay, and tapping Angela Merkel's cellphone.)  Political discussion seems incredibly - err lame - in this venue?  Who started it?  Some dickwad mentions nazis in code, just delete it, obvious.  If you cross him on the street, beat him senseless. Regarding "normal" foul language, I often swear in comments/etc - sometimes people delete it - no big deal.  And now, back to singletons!

Comment: @CodyGray I can say, as one of those Americans, that a crap-ton of us believe it has the "internet meaning", rather than strictly applying it to the government.

Comment: _writes question about offensive question_ .. _starts edit roll back war to add curse words back to question_ derp

Comment: As I said: I have no problem with strong words. Just with hate speech. And ****wit is so silly.

Comment: please see the irony.

Comment: I also have no problem with irony.

Comment: And btw: one rollback is not a war — this would require you to do another rollback.

Comment: i considered doing it, then chose not to because i am anti-war ☮

Comment: Wise decision. And the civilization will collapse because of the human impact on the planet of wars to come because of hate and greed — but not because I use a strong word against myself.

Comment: I think moderators should take care of this, Stack Overflow should not allow any vulgarity or offensiveness

Comment: @MadhavanNR how would you discuss offensiveness if you can't document it? And many moderators took part in the discussion, no one moaned about it. And while sarcasm is something many people don't get easily it isn't forbidden.

Comment: Because of Americans insisting to use ****wit I am tempted to start an experiment: would using a photo of one of my nipples lead to the first nipplegate on stackoverflow?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I'm an American, and I don't think you should have to cover that up with asterisks - not given the semi-quotational context.  It's too close to simply quoting or referring back to the original question.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: I didnt want to say that all americans do such censorship. But in general american society seems to be obsessed with smear words. from an outside respective it looks quite bizarr that every use of certain words gets beeped out in public tv and the whole media and many people go crazy for month if a nipple slips out, while school massacres and drone killings are just answered with shrugs of the shoulders.

Comment: Please stop abusing the "not about S(O|E)" close reason. It hardly applies to anything.

Comment: Why do Germans always feel the need to defend themselves over the second world war? Get over it, it's in the past!

Comment: @StephanBijzitter, this has nothing to do with being German. insulting Jews or the minorities is racism — everywhere.

Comment: @vikingosegundo the two largest paragraphs in your question about Germany, so I would beg to differ.

Comment: This paragraphs explain why I need to know how we want to deal with this shit, as we have a different understand about what is allowed to stay in public and what not, in contrast to many other countries where you can say quite everything.

Comment: btw: why don't you get over this German behavior?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

In this specific case: you'll notice the user responsible for this is currently serving a lengthy suspension. There is a reason for that, and a history here. I'm pretty sure this was an attempt at subtle trolling of the site, and they've done this before. I'm removing the garbage they posted.

In general: does the offensive content directly serve the question being asked? For example, are they asking how to filter that out or parse that kind of text? If so, leave it be. If it has nothing to do with the question being asked, maybe an edit to clean it up might be recommended.

Comment: Tiny note: if you do clean up such questions, make sure you don't forget the answers. If you do, they might look rather odd.

Comment: What about flagging a moderator in addition to the edit, just so that they can keep track of potentially problem users?

Comment: @Cupcake - If it's *really* bad, or you think there's something more to it (like an attempt at trolling, as was the case here), that can't hurt. It might be time to step in and talk to the user at that point.

Comment: Odd, how does a deleted user account serve a lengthy suspension?  Are you saying that suspensions don't actually work at all?  They just keep coming back, creating new accounts?

Comment: While it's of course not your fault, I find it somewhat frustrating that, now that both the user and the question are deleted, most of us now have no way of looking at the content that triggered this action to see whether we agree with it. I understand from the comments on the question that this user had 75k rep, and assume they had a long history of *positive* contributions to the site alongside whatever their past bad behaviour was. Deleting such a user over some infantile offensive humour seems extreme.

Comment: [Screenshot for those who can't see deleted posts](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rXYwC.png)

Comment: @MarkAmery: "*I understand from the comments on the question that this user had 75k rep*" — No. That's a pretty big assumption. It was probably addressed at a [different commenter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255188/should-we-allow-offending-source-code?cb=1#comment23711_255188). The OP of the said question only had 16 rep at the time of asking.

Comment: @MarkAmery - The "75K reputation but still a troll" comment above was meant about Will, not the user we're talking about here. That account had little to its name beyond this question and another, and trust me when I say there's a pattern of abuse around the user behind all of these accounts. We don't remove account with significant contributions, except in the rarest of circumstances. The question involved here is visible to 10k users, if they want to review it.

Comment: @HansPassant - When I first wrote this, that particular account was serving a suspension for a different matter. When I connected the dots and realized it was yet another account of a persistent troll, I removed it. We have means of slowing down folks like this now, and those have been applied to try to prevent them from creating new accounts to troll us with. They were a lot more subtle with their trolling than most.

Comment: I *hate* trolls. Especially the subtle ones. Ever since someone sat down and explained trolling to me, I've been determined to fight this. How can I help?

Comment: Big Yes to this answer, and a small note: editing the question removing or replacing the offensive content would do the job just fine keeping SO clean and sending the message to the offender.

Comment: **tl;dr**: offensive comments for the sake of illustrating a comment, I think, would be fine. Statements obviously designed to troll, or worse, spread malicious or hateful views are something else entirely. *We need a tldroverflow or a tldr.stackoverflow, I think* :D

Comment: I raised a flag against such [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062631/python-quiz-error). It was declined :/

Comment: @shaktimaan - "Offensive" flags carry very severe penalties: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/135615 and should only be used on posts that need to be immediately destroyed. That post is one that I'd recommend suggesting an edit to, since the potentially offensive wording was merely strings used as placeholders in their quiz.

Answer (score 51):

There is already an "offensive, abusive or hate speech" flag for when a post "contains content" that is such.  Having such content in the code is no exception.  The content, if not the question, should be deleted.

Since the OP's intent is likely trolling, it is unlikely that other components of the content represent valuable contributions to Stack Overflow.  If the question is indeed valuable, I don't see why it can't **still** be deleted and replaced with a similar, non-offensive question posted by someone else.

Comment: Deletion is way too big a step when the content is incidental to an actual technical problem.

Comment: Did you mean "... is way too small a step" ?

Comment: Good point! Regarding the original question:  I do believe that a *reasonable* person **should** find it inappropriate.

Comment: You want to delete a possibly great question with possibly great answers (which would all be lost if you post a new question, by the way) just because it contains a single offence sentence that can easily be edited out? Seriously? It's like you don't care about the quality of this site at all, only punishing users who do wrong (which there are way better ways to do, by the way).

Comment: @Dukeling copying the contents of the question and the answers into another question would not lose any content.

Comment: What benefit does this have above simply editing it out? Who's going to do the copying? We could have a moderator merge the questions, but honestly, they have better things to do - an edit can be done by way more people (and merges are very rare AFAIK - not sure why), have other people write up the answers, which would cause the answerers to lose out on that reputation, or have everyone post their answers again, which would just waste everyone's time.

Comment: Right, that's crazy, @Josh?  (or was jot a typo?)  Don't be totally absurd - just delete it completely.  This is a forum for engineers to understand singletons. Obviously, if any idiot mentions an unmentionable (child abuse, naziism, whatever ...) -- perhaps even just as a poorly-managed joke -- just delete it, for goodness sake.  Silly.

Answer (score 30):

Seems pretty darned likely to distract from the technical issue. As such, it falls into the "noise" bin and should be edited to something more neutral:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = @"Did Mickey Mouse really love Minnie?";
```

Comment: How dare you question Micky Mouse's love for Minnie!

Comment: Don't worry, the two buttons are "Yes" and "Heck Yes" @Servy.

Comment: I can't _question_ it until I see some _evidence_ of it! @Servy

Comment: Flagged as offensive for violating Disney copyright. Also, flagged as offensive for mentioning Disney related content on grown-up website.

Comment: This answer is infringing on Disney's Mickey Mouse trademark, and fails to abide by the corporation's licensing standards for the Mickey Mouse character through the use of speech uncharacteristic for the property. Representations of Mickey are not permitted the use of "Heck". The strongest interjections allowed for the character are "Hey!", "Golly!" and "Oh, boy!".

Answer (score 19):

There are cases where something may be offensive to some but it's unavoidable.

> There is both a [language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) and a [Linux Kernel module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_Fuck_Scheduler) called Brainfuck.

- Personally, if someone is offended by this phrase I would say tough luck. That being said, it's not very popular and most exercises in it are academic anyway.

> Someone could make a language called Hitler

- It could call objects Jews.
- It could have collections be called ConcentrationCamps
- Its garbage collector could be the Auschwitz 3.0 library
- Insert any number of tasteless and offensive gimmicks here

This would be absolutely terrible, and it would be very difficult to [take someone who wrote this language seriously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law). If someone did implement a language like this, I would not expect it to last long simply because of how people felt.

If I knew how to use the tool, and someone asked a question about it, I would answer the question because I'm sure the poor soul who is forced to use it at work (or whatever) is enjoying it as little as anyone else. But seriously, someone would make a clone of it with better phrasing. I would never expect this to actually happen, especially with something as inflammatory as WWII, but I could see other potentially offensive things (especially considering culture barriers).

**I would support these questions as one professional trying to help another professional.** I would not feel the need to voice my support or dissent regarding the person using such a library (at least, on account of its name). I trust the person on the other end to use the right tool for the job. If I suggest a different tool, it is because I think that tool can get the job done better, not because its syntax is less offensive.

> There actually is a [library called Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/).

It's a bit outdated now, not having been updated in years, and there just being better options on the market. Officially, it stands for "Apache eXtensible Interaction System" but I suspect many people immediately think of the Axis Powers when they hear the word. No one has any problem supporting this unfortunately named library (at least, they don't have a problem on account of its name... personally I've always hated working with it, but that's just a matter of personal taste.)

The moral of the story is if the offensive material is beyond your control, you should not feel ashamed or embarrassed about it. Words are words, and [we're all adults here](https://stackexchange.com/legal#1AccesstotheServices). If you can avoid offending people, you probably should. The strings mentioned are a prime example of this. There are an infinite number of valid sentences to use, and if you're still in doubt about those, there's always "[foo bar baz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable)" at your disposal.

Comment: I stand on your side on the censorship debate, but the material here is _incidental_ to the technical problem; it can be removed, and life  made more pleasant, without diluting the question's usefulness. If it were _essential_ to the problem, we would be justified in arguing for keeping it.

Comment: If someone has a problem with a library called Axis, I wish them good luck if they ever wish to [do geometry in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_(mathematics)).

Comment: It depends on the word and its larger connotation.  As someone with family that died in the Holocaust, I still don't find the name of the library "Axis" offensive.  The WWII faction is not the word's primary meaning and is unlikely to be the intent of the library's name.  If the library were called "Swastika", however, that's different.  Although the symbol has multiple meanings and was displayed quite innocuously in Roman mosaics (including mosaics from Roman-era synagogues), we all know what the meaning has become.

Comment: >13 does not make an adult.

Comment: @La-comadreja: I suspect the difference is that, whilst the holocaust is inextricably associated with WW2, not everything about WW2 (such as the notion of the "axis powers") is inextricably associated with the holocaust.

Comment: @La-comadreja:  Swastika is actually of Indian origin where it's a symbol of goddess of wealth..

Comment: @Purus. Yes, the nazis made up this arian stuff. And the arian came from India. You find swastikas also in Ancient Greek and Roman Empire. There usually referred to as a sun symbol. But the nazis rotated it by 45 degree.

Comment: This reminds me of the trolls who made a languange to mock feminists (tastelessly too in my opinion) which was defended by some as the pinnacle of free speech!

Comment: @Purus I know.  The Indians actually use the symbol facing in both directions, even today.  And I don't consider it offensive because it is thousands of years old and has nothing to do with Nazis.

Comment: "Words are words, and we're all adults here" This is 100% the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Users who do this should be banned (except, as Brad Larson pointed out, when they're simply referring to ways to filter out such text or, as you've done, quoting it in a question like this).

You mentioned countries that have a strong notion of freedom of speech.  One thing I'll say is that, even in places like the United States, freedom of speech is something the government is bound to, not private organizations.  In each part of the country, not even the culture holds that something like Stack Overflow should be bound to something like that.

This is something that is much more than simply "offensive" though.  "Offensive" is a euphamism for something like this.  People overuse that word, and then it leads to a notion that you can't do anything to offend anybody.  In reality, people will be offended by anything and everything under the sun, no matter what you do.  Nazists are "offended" when you say something negative about Hitler, so we have to allow some forms of offense.

But this is **racism**, not simply offensive speech.  And racism is a particularly evil way of thinking and behaving.  So that being said, I'm glad to see that the user in question is banned, as he should be.

Comment: Wait, asking if "hitler did nothing wrong" is racist? Unless I'm missing part of the OP, that's not racist. And no one should be banned for first time offenses (although I don't think this was his first time)

Comment: @TankorSmash Dude, you probably are missing part of the OP.  If you read further down, you'll see that the code is calling anybody who thinks Hitler did something wrong a ****wit.  So if somebody is anti-Nazist and anti-Holocaust, the code is cursing them out.  It's not that it's asking if "hitler did nothing wrong"?  It's that it's cursing and lashing out at anybody who condemns his racist and imperialist actions.  And that is racist.  (Also it's congratulating those who praise his actions.)  The button tags are what everybody's concerned about.

Comment: Since you were talking about freedom of speech: http://xkcd.com/1357/

Comment: That goes far beyond racism. Racism is a sunday-school activity compared to that.