# This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging

Tags: support, locked-posts

Just going through [Should we allow offensive source code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255188/should-we-allow-offensive-source-code?cb=1)

I wanted to vote/flag the comment, however got a error message as

> [image]

Question: Did I miss something? Is it because question is locked?

Comment: I would assume so. It won't let me vote on any of them. Didn't try flagging in case it worked :/

Comment: I'd personally classify this as a [meta-tag:bug].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post/22229#22229)

> A question or answer which is locked **can no longer accept**:
>
> - edits
> - up-votes, down-votes
> - comments, **comment up-votes**
> - new answers (questions only)
> - close votes, reopen votes (questions only)

Comment: Why is the arrow-up icon displayed if we cannot vote up?

Comment: @P̲̳x͓L̳ Stack Exchange sites do not hide UI elements even if a user cannot use them (due to privileges restriction or any other limitation). Check this answer on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167336/