# Is it OK to use an epithet in the code that is part of a question?

Tags: discussion, offensive

The question [`strcmp()` error after `scanf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290413/strcmp-error-after-scanf) has code which includes the string:

```
"Screw you, learn to follow instructions retard"
```

instead of something more like:

```
"Please read and obey the instructions"
```

I'm sure it is intended to be jocular, but it is borderline offensive. I'm not sure whether to go fix it in the question and the answers (where it got copied), or whether I am being too sensitive. Just dropping 'retard' would be an improvement.

I also searched for 'retard' in other questions on SO, and there were some places where it was used in the sense 'slow down', and a few where the OP described themselves or their question as retarded.  The technical uses I have no problem with.  I'm not so sure about the others, but there was nothing else egregious that I noticed.

(I flagged it about seven hours ago with a custom explanation, but it isn't easy for a mod to fix.  If there was a mechanism for them to tell me "yes — go ahead and fix it for us" or "no — you're being way to politically correct", it would be easier, but I suspect their options are a bit too limited for that to be easily conveyed.)

My question is:

- Should someone (e.g. me) fix the string along the lines suggested?

I'm quite willing to do it; I'm just not quite sure whether it is appropriate.

This question is clearly closely related to [Should we allow offensive source code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255188/should-we-allow-offensive-source-code) but differs in asking whether this particular example is offensive, as opposed to the sample in that question.

### Fixed

With no objections raised, I've edited the strings to avoid the possibility of the code seeming offensive.

Comment: The code has since been changed. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The essence of the code that is desired is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Parts of the code (and strings within the code) that distract from the problem, well, they distract from the problem and make the code example non-minimal.

Changing the code so that it is something that people won't complain about but still demonstrates the problem and is veritably not going to cause other errors to crop up, would likely be considered a good change for someone with full edit rights.

Seeing such wording on the site that *isn't* corrected acts as a broken window.  People complain about the rudeness of the elite and comments and whatnot.  Having text presented that isn't a necessary part of the question (compare a vulgarity checker) fosters the expectation that yes, it is acceptable to be rude to others within the text of the question (and comments).

Furthermore, the questions and answers are the public face of Stack Overflow.  Ideally, every post should be of the highest quality.  While we don't have sufficient volunteering power to make that a reality, it *can* and *should* be acted upon to correct what the rest of the world sees here.  Having such text in the code is just as bad as having a giant 'include' starting off a question.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the giant include statements (and your good answer). Markdown took a bit for me to get used to when I started here, but do posters not even look at their rendered questions before posting?

Comment: @SLawson: I'm slowly getting used to [being told off after commenting on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207856/notepad-remove-all-before-first-character). Nowadays, it hardly raises my blood pressure anymore.

Comment: @SLawson: I certainly appreciate it when someone improves my formatting, or points out issues with it, but want to say that on several occasions where someone fixed ifor me, the preview and the final view differed.

Answer (score 9):

(Too long as a comment.)

Since you've asked about whether or not calling someone a retard is offensive this falls into "opinion" and should be closed. The real question is "should it be edited".

Yes, it should, because the question you asked *can* be legitimately asked, and the potentially offensive wording detracts from what is otherwise simply trivially searchable--still fairly low quality.

The signal-to-noise ratio of the question is *further* exacerbated by the opening sentence, most of which is completely irrelevant and could be shortened, and be better, as only the bold portion:

*I realize this is a really dumb question, but it's been ages since I last did some C coding, and* **I seem to have forgotten how to use strcmp().**

IMO to make the question as concise as possible, *all* the unnecessary fluff should be removed. Since the technical bits of the question are unchanged by any of the strings in question, and is not aided in any way by the "I'm so dumb" bits, go all the way, and fix *all* of it to be a better fit for SO.

Comment: Fair comment. I did some minimal cleanup when I changed the string.  I just went back and did some more cleanup to the introduction — it is now in SO-ready shape.  It still isn't a very good question, but it is now sanitized.

Answer (score 3):

It is acceptable in very rare circumstances, when the foul language is pertinent to the post.

That generally means questions related to automated detection of foul language ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14216524/103167))

Any time it would be possible to convey the meaning using only polite language, do.

Comment: A problem with the question you linked to is that language evolves, and yesterday's adjective can be tomorrows offensive language. Calling someone a "liberal", for example, is slowly edging that way.

Comment: @Jongware: If someone is uncomfortable by having their political philosophy recognized, perhaps they should rethink their adherence to it.  Anyway, this discussion seems to be about arbitrary labels, not those that are factually descriptive.  Whether to use PC terminology for factually descriptive (e.g. if the word "retard" from this meta question were actually being used in the sense of a learning disability) labels would be a different issue.

Comment: @Jongware A more common example is "spastic" which was originally the medical term for cerebral palsy, and has evolved into the insult to the point where I've seen people reluctant to use the medical term [Spasticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spasticity).

Comment: @BenVoigt If someone is uncomfortable by engaging in coitus with a maternal progenitor... Also, "retard" isn't used for people with learning disabilities any more either. The loss of "spasticity" is a pain, though.