# To what extent would offensive content be considered "repairable"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, offensive, code-of-conduct

Just now [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674944) containing offensive and vulgar words [was caught](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44177953#44177953) by a moderation bot. We had some divergence about whether that question is "repairable". That is, some people think the question isn't repairable because it is directly offensive and insulting to readers, while some others argue that it's repairable because it looks like a typical question from new user with offensive words added. We discussed further about "repairability" in general, but still couldn't come to a consensus.

I would like to know what the Stack Overflow community think about "repairability of posts containing offensive content", and what the community think about this specific post.

---

For <10k, here's the post content:

> ## How can I add an infinite loop for this code?(I am new, don't troll thx)
>
> import sys
>
> print("Tell me your score asshole: ")
>
> result= int(input())
>
> if result > 1 and result < 50:
>
> ```
> print("You have won a wooden rabbit")
> ```
>
> elif result > 51 and result < 150:
>       print("You ain't won shit!")
>
> elif result > 151 and result < 180:
>       print("You have won a wafer-thin mint")
>
> elif result > 181 and result < 200:
>       print("You have won a penguin")
>
> elif result > 200 and result < 1001:
>       print("Stop bugging me, fuck off!!")

Comment: In this case it's definitely reparable, since the only really offensive words are in string literals. It would still be trash after changing them, just not offensive trash.

Comment: @StephenLeppik my worry is that the OP would soon roll back anyways.

Comment: In which case, flag and let mods deal with them. You can assume good faith at first, but that goes out the window if it gets rolled back.

Comment: I am all for repairing and (thereby) attempting to teach the ways of StackOverflow. But am I the only one having a bad feeling that there is only one kind of users who have the concept of trolling so foremost in their mind (while phrasing a question) that they mention it in their title AND then use needlessly questionable and provocative wording?

Comment: @Yunnosch While there are some indicators that things might not go well with respect to the user's response to an edit removing the offensive language and a comment informing them of the requirement for professional language, that doesn't absolve us from the responsibility to assume good faith. In this case, it literally takes around 30s–2m to perform the edit and leave a comment. If the user does respond negatively, flag and walk away.

Comment: Does it need repairing?

Comment: Definitely not a minimal example.

Comment: "pls don't troll" is the surest mark of a troll if there's one

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255188/should-we-allow-offensive-source-code?rq=1)

Comment: `elif result > 181 and result < 200:`: OP is not using chaining operators: the post is just unsalvageable.

Comment: We need a SNOWFLAKE badge.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre While I agree that the post is unsalvageable, this question specifically focuses on its offensiveness and less on its overall quality.

Comment: My score is 50 ...

Comment: Why import sys at the beggining?

Comment: @10Rep That's not the point of this Meta post.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Assume good faith

We should assume good faith: repair such posts (without the offensive language, there's actually a question/answer); inform the user with a calmly worded comment that SO/SE requires using professional language and that [offensive language isn't acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233). If the user *continues* to not comply with those standards (e.g. makes additional similar posts, or rolls back the edit to this post), then flag for moderator attention.

### This post is repairable

The repair is, primarily, to remove the 4 offensive words. Given that we're already editing it, then clean up the grammar around where the offensive words were used. In addition, remove the text "(I am new, don't troll thx)" from the title.

Repaired, the question looks like:

> ## How can I add an infinite loop for this code?
>
> ```
> import sys
> print("Tell me your score: ")
> result= int(input())
> if result > 1 and result < 50:
>     print("You have won a wooden rabbit.")
> elif result > 51 and result < 150: print("You didn't win.")
> elif result > 151 and result < 180: print("You have won a wafer-thin mint.")
> elif result > 181 and result < 200: print("You have won a penguin.")
> elif result > 200 and result < 1001: print("Stop bugging me.")
> ```

While I don't think this is a good question, it is a question. It could use a bit more explanation, but what the OP is wanting is quite narrow and clear enough once you think about what they might want a little bit. They could/should explain what they want a bit better.

Comment: Agreed. Colorful language can trivially be replaced by less colorful language (without affecting the original intent).

Comment: it's a question of limit. 1 or 2 swear words can be edited out, but there are 10 lines of code and 5 edits. It's a bit like retyping images of code... not worth it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre To remove the offensive portion is literally just removing 4 words. The rest of the edits are ones which should be done when editing. Although, removing the "(I am new, don't troll thx)" would justify it's own edit, even if the offensive words weren't there.

Comment: but you have to imagine non-offensive sentences that mean roughly the same. Too much work :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ahh... OK. :-) I don't see it as that much work. The offensive portion can really be removed by *just* taking out 4 words. Yes, that did require mentally checking each one with the offensive content removed prior to making a choice to edit, or not. If it was really necessary to completely reword/rework the text, then, yeah, I might agree that it's gone beyond where we should be correcting things for OPs. That's something that's quite situational and varies on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I don't agree with this. When you chose to post something on the Internet, for the world to see, you need to use decorum and common sense. If they can't produce a civil example, they won't get any answers and we may delete the question. It is not the job of SO to raise children (or children in adult bodies) and teach them how to behave in public. This is a programming site, not daycare.

Answer (score 15):

I'm leaving my (partial) opinion here.

I left this comment on that question and it got 1 vote.

> Given the amount of rude content in this question, I consider more a rant than a valid question and have flagged as such.

Others have argued that "All it would take is to remove 4 words". While I agree with this, it won't make it a good question. Additionally, the general language in the question is unfriendly and unkind (e.g. "no troll thx" in title), and therefore it's more a rant and better not repaired.

IMO, repairability is like a few "f***ing" misused as "very", or a sane amount of vulgar words in an expression of despair or frustration, but not and never such direct offense and insult like this one.

The code itself may look reasonable* and repairable, but if one is not taught to refrain from being offensive, then it's probably not our (Stack Overflow community's) job to teach them to be civilized and polite. OTOH, misused vulgar words are more easily taught to be avoided, if the intention wasn't to insult. We answer their programming questions, but we're not to teach them how to behave.

From another perspective, I consider them "repairable" if such posts won't be considered "disruptive" even if they come in a larger volume (if not to the extent of trolling). But if more posts of a type come and they become disrupting, then it's the unacceptable type. That says, I won't feel much uneasy if many posts contain vulgar words in sentences or frustration, but I *will* feel upset if I see many posts like this, which I call "directly offensive to readers". That makes it rather clear what repairability is.

**For this specific case**, there's an extra thing that I've taken into account: It appears that the author knows what "trolling" is and have asked us "not to troll on them" in the first place (in title), which adds another reason to the consideration of it being affronting.

---

* The code looks reasonable because (I agree with this text)

> The code follows a fairly typical pattern for an early effort of a young (low-mid teenage) person getting into coding. It's the sort of thing that we've seen many times. A reasonable percentage of them are receptive to having the offensive portions edited out and being informed that such language isn't professional, thus not acceptable here (on Stack Overflow). ([Makyen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47055829#47055829))

Comment: *"no troll thx"* is meta content and as such should just be removed from the question.

Comment: `"...but if one is not taught to refrain from being offensive, then it's probably not our ... job to teach them to be civilized and polite."` Repair the question, and monitor the account. We have mechanisms to "teach" good behavior. By not repairing an apparent 1st-offender's post, you are teaching him that SO does "troll" in this person's mind.

Comment: @usr2564301 nobody has to answer it, and the fix is fairly simple. Sure the OP might laugh if answered (or might not laugh because it was a real question), that's not our concern for one question. The monitoring is important. If this behavior continues, then actions must be taken. Nobody has to go out of their way (except for the OP to write all these bad questions)

Comment: Re: "such direct offense and insult like this one": Wait, what? Do you really feel that the question was trying to insult readers and give them offense?

Comment: @ruakh You code interactive programs in this way?

Comment: @iBug: I do not insist that everyone be like me. If the OP thinks that the user will find the jokes funny, then I see nothing wrong with them. It's not as if they were racist/sexist/etc., or insulted other people, or anything like that. (It doesn't belong on SO, of course, but that's why we have an 'edit' button.)

Comment: @iBug Well, you stated that you agree that the poster is likely a young or inexperienced coder based on their coding patterns. Does it not follow then that they would have a teenage sense of humor? It's strange, given that you've already accepted the above, that you assume the poster is trying to insult you. Sure, edit if you want, but you shouldn't simply assume that this person is going to be a jerk, for eternity, because they made this one post. I remember one time, decades ago, when I might have thought this was funny.

Comment: "Hey no troll thx". If someone writes that in a post i would consider them a troll.

Answer (score 6):

Would this content be fine if sent as a service request to a company or as a business letter? Of course it would not, it would get deleted and ignored. You would perhaps even get blocked from contacting that company again. Why would SO be any different?

This is because a certain amount of decorum and common sense is expected when humans communicate with each other, particularly if they don't know each other in advance.

- Teaching people how grown-ups act in public is not a task for SO.
- This a programming site, not daycare. We don't have to be patient and forgiving.
- Despite popular belief, we don't need to salvage every single piece of crap ever posted to the site.

There is nothing to ponder - just delete the post. Flag for moderator attention if it is particularly rude.