# How do you approach or salvage a question with sexist overtones?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381363/discord-bot-smash-or-pass) question today, and I knew it would cause some sort of flagging.

Now, let's assume for a moment that this question was valid, well written, and aside from the code/purpose, all together a good question. Would a flag still be valid there for the content/purpose of the code?

With the new Code of Conduct, does the conduct extend itself into the nature of the program as well? (Beyond the comments)

Comment: Ultimately the whole sexist part was completely irrelevant to the problem being asked about.

Comment: Possibly related? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375019/to-what-extent-would-offensive-content-be-considered-repairable Changing a few of the string literals in the code and the corresponding mentions of them in the text wouldn't change the intent of the question, so it would be "repairable" in this case.

Comment: Screenshot for those of us <10k?

Comment: I think current state question is covered by one found by @KevinB https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375019/to-what-extent-would-offensive-content-be-considered-repairable (which I chose as duplicate). If you are more interested in whether flagging is needed - let's edit the post to clarify and re-open.

Comment: Honestly? Yeah a flag would still be valid. I would be hard-pressed to decline it, even if I think the responsibility should fall on the author to pick an acceptable example (it's not a mod's responsibility to conjure up a new snippet with so many of the strings and data having to be replaced, especially for something as substantial as this).

Comment: @BoltClock I think your comment should be converted into an answer. Should this question be clarified as "When to flag posts with offensive/sexists code samples" or you would prefer to keep one post with all guidance?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: It's not a topic I'd like to go into in depth at the moment.